# Get instance to call method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to set the value of a colorpicker. I'm using this color picker:
http://mjolnic.github.io/bootstrap-colorpicker/

The colorpicker is bound to a html element with jquery:

```
$('.sample-selector').colorpicker({ /*options...*/ });
```

It also has a few methods like:

```
.setColor(value)
```

How can i get the colorpicker instance so i can call a method?

I tried a lot of things. First i init colorpicker:

```
$('#thecolor').colorpicker();
```

This works. But i can't seem to find a way to call a method:

```
$('#thecolor').colorpicker.toRGB()
$('#thecolor').toRGB()
$('#thecolor').colorpicker().toRGB()
```

and so on. It must but something really small :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the colorpicker instance from the DOM:

```
var cp = $('#thecolor').data().colorpicker;
```

The color object is a property:

```
cp.color.toRGB();
```

Comment: jqueries data saves the day: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/ . Did not yet know that one. Thanks! And also cheers to everyone else trying to help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

From the `bootstrap-colorpicker` doc, you can call `toRGB` like this:

```
$('#thecolor').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
    console.log(ev.color.toRGB());
});
```

Comment: It's almost a copy/paste from the documentation so I have no idea (other than butthurt) why someone would down-vote this.  It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed this line:

> Color object methods
>
> Each triggered events have a color object used internally by the picker. This object has several useful methods.

Look at the following example:

```
$('.my-colorpicker-control').colorpicker().on('changeColor', function(ev){
    bodyStyle.backgroundColor = ev.color.toHex();
});
```

So it's not available from the outside. You can try to hack around that (not tested)

```
$('.my-colorpicker-control').colorpicker().on('create', function(ev) {
    window.mycolorpicker = ev.color;
});

if (window.mycolorpicker) {
    window.mycolorpicker.setColor('...');
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

Try this:

```
var colorPicker = $("#thecolor").colorpicker();
$(colorPicker).toRGB(); // object method
```